# Is this proof regarding odd perfect numbers valid?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

(**Edited in response to a comment.**)

Here are my:

**QUESTIONS**

> **(1)** Is this proof regarding odd perfect numbers valid, particularly the part where it says
> $$\dfrac{2n^2}{D(n^2)} \neq (q + 1)?$$

> **(2)** If the proof is incorrect, how can the argument be mended to produce a valid proof?

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special/Euler prime $q$.  (That is, $\gcd(q,n)=1$ and $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.)  Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the *sum of the divisors* of $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

Define
$$D(n^2) := 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)$$
to be the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of the non-Euler part $n^2$.

Define
$$I(n^2) := \dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2}$$
to be the *abundancy index* of $n^2$.

Since $N$ is perfect, then we have
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(N)=2N=2q^k n^2$$
from which it follows that
$$I(N)=2 \iff I(q^k)I(n^2)=2.$$

But since $q$ is prime, $I(q^k)$ can be rewritten as
$$I(q^k) = \dfrac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q^k (q - 1)}$$
which can be bounded as follows (since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies that $k \geq 1$)
$$\frac{q+1}{q} = I(q) \leq I(q^k) < \dfrac{q^{k+1}}{q^k (q - 1)} = \frac{q}{q - 1}.$$

This implies that
$$\dfrac{2(q - 1)}{q} < I(n^2) = \dfrac{2}{I(q^k)} \leq \dfrac{2q}{q + 1}$$
from which it follows that
$$\dfrac{2}{q+1} \leq 2 - I(n^2) = \dfrac{D(n^2)}{n^2} < \dfrac{2}{q},$$
which means that
$$q < \dfrac{2n^2}{D(n^2)} \leq (q + 1).$$
Since $2n^2$ is even and $D(n^2) = 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)$ is always odd (since $n^2$ is a square), then $$\dfrac{2n^2}{D(n^2)}$$
**cannot be an integer**.  This implies that
$$\dfrac{2n^2}{D(n^2)} \neq (q + 1)$$
which implies that
$$\dfrac{n^2}{D(n^2)} \neq \dfrac{q+1}{2}$$
and
$$2 - I(n^2) = \dfrac{D(n^2)}{n^2} \neq \dfrac{2}{q+1}.$$
Finally, we obtain
$$I(n^2) \neq \bigg(2 - \dfrac{2}{q+1}\bigg) = \dfrac{2q}{q+1}$$
which implies that
$$I(q^k) = \dfrac{2}{I(n^2)} \neq \dfrac{q+1}{q},$$
thus resulting in
$$k \neq 1.$$

Comment: What is the statement you are proving?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @LeeMosher!  Basically, I am trying to show that
$$\dfrac{2n^2}{D(n^2)}=\dfrac{2n^2}{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)} \neq (q + 1)$$
is **true**.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to state that up front. It's very hard to start reading through a proof without knowing what is being proved.

Comment: My apologies.  Doing so now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)**

Your proof looks invalid to me.

You are saying "Since $2n^2$ is even and $D(n^2) = 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)$ is always odd (since $n^2$ is a square), then $\dfrac{2n^2}{D(n^2)}$ cannot be an integer".

This is not true since $\frac{\text{even}}{\text{odd}}$ can be an integer. For example, $\frac{6}{3}=2$.

---

Since $D(n^2)$ is odd, we have
$$\frac{2n^2}{D(n^2)}\in\mathbb Z\iff D(n^2)\mid n^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @mathlove.

Comment: An interesting and specific counterexample is $n=3003$, which gives $q=22021$ and leads to the only known [Descartes number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes_number).

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about the Descartes spoof, @nickgard!